# Low resolution in MacVim. Bug?

Tags: macos, vim, screen-resolution, macvim

`MacVim` is on the left, and to the right is Terminal.app running `vim`.

`MacVim`'s app is clearly rendered in a different, *lower* resolution.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

#### Zooming In

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and squashed, well not exactly.

If I launch MacVim from the terminal `mvim ...` there are no problems. The issue is when running the app from the GUI, i.e., clicking on icon.